# Shows: provision invalid subplatform

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

If i want to regenerate provisioning with new certificate then its showing below pop-up.

[image]

Note: I have created new certificate and then try again but same issue.

Comment: Seems a bug in Apple Site. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479493/provision-invalid-subplatform-invalid-sub-platform-for-platform

Comment: I had tried after 2 hrs and everything was working for me.